# Counterexample to see that a formula is $F$

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

How to find an interpretation $I$ such that make the following formula false?

$$\forall x\forall y\forall z(A(x,x)\land (A(x,z)\to A(x,y)\lor A(y,z)))\to\exists y\forall z A(y,z)$$

I tried with 3 interpretations but all failed :(

$I_1$ with domain $\mathbb N, A(x,y)="x=y"$

$I_2$ with domain $\mathbb N, A(x,y)="x,y $ are both even"

$I_3$ with domain $\mathbb N, A(x,y)="x<y"$

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried negating the formula?

Comment: @DanielV no, if I negate the formula, then I would need to find an interpretation that make it true?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close! Try $A(x,y): x \ge y$

Comment: how did you realize about it? I wanna find the trick :D

Comment: @michelle The statement is a conditional and for it to be false the antecedent has to be true and the consequent false. The true antecedent means that $A$ has to be reflexive, and the false consequent means that you need $\forall y \exists z \neg A(y,z)$. So, inspired by your attempts to work with the natural numbers, I first tried $\le$ ($<$ does not work since it is not reflexive), found it works nicely to make the s cons part of the antecedent true, but unfortunately run into a problem with $0$ so the consequent would not be false. So, I had to change it to $\ge$

Comment: I see, what would you have done if $\ge$ had failed? what else would you try?

Comment: @michelle Then I would have tried something less 'meaningful' or 'familiar' like numbersare, and just consider a domain with one, two, three, or four objects, and just assign the A relation if needed. In fact, let's try exactly that ... now, I know I need more than one object, since every object stands in the W relation to itself but with the consequent having to be false I need every object to lack an A relation with something.  OK , so let's try two objects a and b .. so we need A(a,a) and A(b,b) but not A(a,b) and also not A(b,a) ... (continued)

Comment: .... but this does not work with the second half of the antecedent. Ok, let's try three objects. Again we have aAa, bAb and now also cAc. Now, we als need either aAb or bAa ... let's just pick aAb and let's not have bAa... likewise, let's pick bAc and not cAb and finally let's do pick aAc and not cA. OK, so the consequent is now false ... but now that we added aAb we need either aAc or cAb ... we have aAc: good!sincebAc we  also need either bAa or aAc ...we have aAc: good! Finally by aAc we need aAb or bAc : we have both: good! So, this works! .... but as you can see, this is trial and error.

Comment: oh I didn't expect that answer for my last question. Thank you.